# issue while installing jenkins in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, jenkins, ubuntu-16.04

Tried installing jenkins by following the below mentioned link but end up facing the following issue

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/installing-jenkins-on-ubuntu-16-04/

```
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code
```

Reinstalled the dpkg again and tried installing jenkins but end up facing the same issue

```
Could someone please guide me to resolve this issue?

uday@uday:~$ sudo apt-get install jenkins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
jenkins is already the newest version (2.204.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-57 linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up jenkins (2.204.1) ...
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-12-22 20:09:44 IST; 4ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 31293 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 22 20:09:44 uday jenkins[31293]: Found an incorrect Jav...
Dec 22 20:09:44 uday jenkins[31293]: Java version found:
Dec 22 20:09:44 uday jenkins[31293]: java version "1.7.0_95"
Dec 22 20:09:44 uday jenkins[31293]: OpenJDK Runtime Enviro...
Dec 22 20:09:44 uday jenkins[31293]: OpenJDK Server VM (bui...
Dec 22 20:09:44 uday jenkins[31293]: Aborting
Dec 22 20:09:44 uday systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control p...
Dec 22 20:09:44 uday systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start...
Dec 22 20:09:44 uday systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Unit ente...
Dec 22 20:09:44 uday systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed wi...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Tried getting the Output of journalctl -xe command to observe the issue

```
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit jenkins.service has begun starting up.
Dec 23 08:21:32 uday jenkins[3105]: Found an incorrect Java version
Dec 23 08:21:32 uday jenkins[3105]: Java version found:
Dec 23 08:21:32 uday jenkins[3105]: java version "1.7.0_95"
Dec 23 08:21:32 uday jenkins[3105]: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-3)
Dec 23 08:21:32 uday jenkins[3105]: OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
Dec 23 08:21:32 uday jenkins[3105]: Aborting
Dec 23 08:21:32 uday systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 23 08:21:32 uday systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
-- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit jenkins.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 23 08:21:32 uday systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 23 08:21:32 uday systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 23 08:21:33 uday sudo[3002]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 23 08:21:43 uday sudo[3170]:     uday : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/uday ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Dec 23 08:21:43 uday sudo[3170]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
~
```

Comment: what is the result of `journalctl -xe`?

Comment: Added it in the question

Comment: Try to upgrade the version of java: **Found an incorrect Java version**

Comment: look here https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/ for more details

Comment: afaik jenkins requires a java runtime environment (jre) version of 8...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not "Programming" related it is probably better asked on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the new version of Jenkins only supports OpenJDK-8 So you should clean all the installed Java and Jenkins and reinstall it according to this post https://techpostal.blogspot.com/2020/01/jenkins-installation-in-ubuntu-1804.html   hope it will help you..